# Angular 2 handleError request method

Tags: angular

post request

```
post(url, data, params = {}, headers = {}) {
        this.loaderService.show();
        return this.http
            .post(url, data, this.options(params, headers))
            .map(this.transformResponse)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .finally(() => {
                this.loaderService.hide();
            });
    }
```

option method

```
private options (params, headers) {
        let _headers = new Headers();
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {
            _headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token'));
        }
        _headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        _headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        let _search = new URLSearchParams();
        if (params instanceof URLSearchParams) {
            _search.replaceAll(params);
        }else {
            for (let param in params) {
                _search.set(param, params[param]);
            }
        }

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: _headers, search: _search});

        return options;
    }
```

my error handling

```
private handleError = (err) => {
let res = {
            status: err.status,
            statusText: err.statusText,
            data: {}
        };}
```

how to capture the requested method in my `handleError function`

the current response which i am getting is

```
response_body: "{↵  "associateToken": "SDFWETSDFSDFW4"↵}"headers: Headers_headers: Map_normalizedNames: Map__proto__: Objectok: falsestatus: 403statusText: "Forbidden"type: 2url: "xyz.com"
```

how to get request method post or get in the above response. Any inputs is highly appreciated.

Comment: you want to log the error if it from post or get is that so ?

Comment: @RahulSingh yeah i want to known for which method i got the error.

Comment: you could pass a parameter to the handleError method and then use it to differentiate between post and get like a string key . G for get and P for Post and that will do the trick for you in handleError method

Comment: @RahulSingh I tired the adding the post and get in the handleError function with the  below method way [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html). but its still the same

Comment: what i am telling is in the .catch(this.handleError('G')) and in the handleError(value:string) use something like this

Comment: @RahulSingh tired above method i get error has `Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<any>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: can you post a plunker of the same ?